# Doctrine FIND_IN_SET leads to Error: Expected end of string, got '('

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-extensions

I've got the following doctrine query in Symfony2:

```
$query = $em
    ->createQuery("
        SELECT m FROM MyBackendBundle:Merchant m
        WHERE m.active = :active
        ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(m.range, 'all', 'without_special'), m.tradingAmount DESC
    ")
    ->setParameter('active', true)
;
```

But this leads to the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 112: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

and:

```
QueryException: 
SELECT m FROM My\Bundle\BackendBundle\Entity\Merchant m 
WHERE m.active = :active 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(m.range, 'all', 'without_special') ASC, m.tradingAmount DESC
```

I use the `FIND_IN_SET` [doctrine extension from beberlei](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) to be able to use it in the query.

Any ideas why this happens?

**Update:**

Using the `FIND_IN_SET` in the SELECT as an alias this way:

```
SELECT m, FIND_IN_SET(m.range, 'all', 'without_special') AS HIDDEN findInSet
FROM MyBackendBundle:Merchant 
WHERE m.active = :active
ORDER BY findInSet, m.productAmount DESC
```

results in the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 56: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','
```

Comment: I'm not sure but i don't think you can use functions in the `order_by`. One way would be to create an alias for that result like `SELECT m, FIND_IN_SET(m.range, 'all', 'without_special') as HIDDEN findInSet FROM ....` and then use that alias in the `order_by` instead.

Comment: Tried that, results in: `QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 53: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','` Which doesn't make that much sense to me, because there is a closing parenthesis, but no comma.

Comment: Sorry, col 56 instead of 53

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. It doesn't look like `FIND_IN_SET` takes 3 arguments, either in the extensions pack or in MySQL in general. If `all` and `without_special` are supposed to be the set then I think they are supposed to be in 1 arguments like `FIND_IN_SET(m.range, 'all,without_special')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @qooplmao this is the working version:

```
$query = $em
    ->createQuery("
        SELECT m, FIND_IN_SET(m.range, 'all,without_special') AS rangeOrdering
        FROM MyBackendBundle:Merchant m
        WHERE m.active = :active
        ORDER BY rangeOrdering, m.tradingAmount DESC
    ")
    ->setParameter('active', true)
;
```

`FIND_IN_SET` has only two parameters and has to be within the `SELECT` part of the query as functions can't be used in the `ORDER BY` part of the query.