# Can't found the FIND_IN_SET method in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In my repository class. I did a specific query ro retrieve the data from database. I have a column with a content like this `44,55,22`. So, I'am using the `FIND_IN_SET` method to find a specific number in a set.

I tried to transpose this in Symfony

```
$query->orWhere($query->expr()->andX('f.private = :private',"FIND_IN_SET({$user->getId()},'f.toUsers')"));
```

But I got this Symfony error which means that the method is absent.

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 821: Error: Expected known function, got 'FIND_IN_SET'"

Comment: Is the content of your field a list of foreign keys serialized?

Comment: May be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246126/doctrine-find-in-set-leads-to-error-expected-end-of-string-got

Comment: @Cid No, it is not the case.

Comment: @JulesR. The response to this question is not really adapted to mine. Thanks

Comment: This still looks like a badly designed table. You should consider normalisation.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

Here is the solution to this problem for anyone who confronts it.

First, you should add this line to the `config.yml` file

```
orm:
  dql:
    string_functions:
      FIND_IN_SET: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\FindInSet
```

This is required for Symfony to know where function is located.

In your repository class you can call the function this way (it is just an example) `$query->OrWhere("FIND_IN_SET({$user->getId()},'55') <> 0");`